# mongoose | how to get all documents according to day of the week

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to get all the documents that matches a given **day of the week**.

for example, if this is how my DB looks like:

```
{name: "first", created: ISODate("2020-07-16T14:47:21.065+0000")},
{name: "second", created: ISODate("2020-07-23T14:47:21.065+0000")},
{name: "third", created: ISODate("2020-07-30T14:47:21.065+0000")},
{name: "forth", created: ISODate("2020-07-31T14:47:21.065+0000")}
```

And I would like to get all the documents that were created on **Thursday** (which are the first 3 documents).

How do I achieve that?

Also is it possible to get all documents of a given day of the week and a given hour? (e.g: all documents that were created on Thursday between 08:00-09:00)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using an aggregation with operators like [$dayOfWeek](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/) and [$hour](https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/operator/aggregation/hour.html) like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $hour: "$created"
              },
              8/** only hour 8*/
              
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$dayOfWeek": "$created"
              },
              5/**thursday*/
              
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cpiCMNtDHuI)

This query will match all documents from a Thursday between the hours 8-9. Mind you this is not just the past week but all previous dates. If you want it in a certain range (i.e current week only) you need to add another condition to the query.